# Stable polynomials have positive coefficients

Tags: polynomials, stability-in-odes

Consider the polynomial
$$P(x)=x^n+a_{n-1} x^{n-1}+\dots+a_1 x+a_0 $$
with real coefficients $\{a_i\}$. It is called stable if all its roots have negative real part. The [Routh-Hurwitz stability criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routh%E2%80%93Hurwitz_stability_criterion) gives a characterization of stable polynomials. However, I'm looking for a simpler way to show the following non-characterizing property

> If $P(x)$ is stable, then all of its coefficients are positive.

I've tried using Vieta's formulas, as well the Laplace transform, but couldn't do it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A (monic) polynomial with real coefficients can be written as a product of

- linear factors $x - a$, corresponding to a real zero of $P$, and
- quadratic factors, corresponding to a pair of complex-conjugate zeroes
  $a - ib$, $a+ib$ of $P$.

Each quadratic factor is of the form
$$
 (x - a - ib)(x - a + ib) = (x-a)^2 + b^2
$$

with $b \ne 0$.
It follows that if all zeros of $P$ have negative real part then
it can be written as a product of monic polynomials with 
*positive* coefficients.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming real coefficients .  . .

Assume all the roots have negative real part.

For the real roots $r$, if any, the corresponding factor $(x-r)$ has positive coefficients.

For the non-real roots, pair them up as $r,\bar{r}$, and note that the quadratic polynomial
$$(x-r)(x-\bar{r})$$
has positive coefficients.

Then just multiply the quadratic factors and the real linear factors.

Done!

Comment: Why can $P$ not have a real root?

Comment: Oops ...${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @Martin R: Thanks for the alert. Fixed.